# Laravel App Not Loading CSS From Public Installation Not In public_html

Tags: laravel, directory, environment-variables

I've installed a pre-made Laravel app and followed the documentation to extract it to the public root except in the documentation they are installing it into public_html, but I have it in a subdomain in a folder named "test" which is on the same level as public_html.

All the CSS and JS should be loading from the public subdirectory, but they try to look for it in the main root folder.

For example, this file returns a 404 error:
https://test.mydomain.com/css/style.css

The file is actually at this location:
https://test.mydomain.com/public/css/style.css

The absolute path of the file is:
**/home/mydomain/test/public/css/style.css**

Instead of:
**/home/mydomain/public_html/public/css/style.css**

What environment or config file isn't set correctly and how do I set it to use the correct directory?

**UPDATE**

Changing the ASSET_URL to "public" fixed the first issue, but now the same thing is happening with the admin.

The app tries to load the dashboard with this URL:
https://test.mydomain.com/admin/dashboard

The page loads all the assets normally when I remove the word "admin" from the URL:
https://test.mydomain.com/dashboard

But this doesn't work for all the pages.

Comment: Did you try assign path in config/app.php (asset_url) key ?

Comment: How are you compiling the css using `asset` or using absolute path?

Comment: You put your laravel `public` directory files on `public_html` and your laravel files located outside of `public_html`?

Comment: @RavikantPatel please send in an answer and I'll upvote. This worked by setting the ASSET_URL to public.

Comment: yes, answer is added. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put public directory path in below given conflagration file.

Config File Path :  **config/app.php (asset_url)**

```
 'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', 'https://test.mydomain.com/public/')
```